# iOS native app finding what a story is linking to : status, photo etc

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

Entries in a news feed of type story do not seem to identify what they are about other than in the text so I cannot programatically tell if it's about their own status, a photo etc other than looking at the works in the message.

Is there a way of identifying what a story refers to (so I can make meaningful looking posts like 'Jane commented on her own status - "My new iPad is great for reading magazines" ')

I'm stuck as I can tell if I should fetch a post , photo or whatever.

Thanks in advance

Ian
sundialSoft
in a rather wet Scotland.